# Cannot access 'androidx.lifecycle.HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory' which is a supertype of 'FavoriteBottomDialogFragment'. Check your module cla

Tags: android, dependencies, classpath, androidx, bottom-sheet

I am getting error in the whole class that extends BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
Cannot access 'androidx.lifecycle.HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory' which is a supertype of 'FavoriteBottomDialogFragment'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

[image]

[image]

The class is in app module and this module implements two other modules : core and presentation-core

build.gradle

```
dependencies {

     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation project (':core')
     implementation project (':presentation-core')

     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.41"
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"

     //Rx
     implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
     implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9"
     //Architecture component
     implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
     implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
     kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'
     kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0'
     implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0'
     implementation 'androidx.room:room-guava:2.0.0'

     implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
     implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
 }
```

core dependencies

```
dependencies {
     api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.61"
     api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.4"
     api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.2'
     //library to serialize Java Objects between Contexts
     implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.11'
     kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.11'

     //testing dependencies
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
     testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.5"
     androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5"

     //architecture component
     implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
     implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0"

     //RxJava2
     implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9"
     implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
}
```

presentation-core

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.61"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
}
```

**BottomSheetDialogFragment**
[image]

Even with errors i got, I can run the project in a device

Comment: I have been running into that as well. There's a bug in an inspection or Lint rule somewhere. I filed [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152245564), which Google declined. For some book samples, I wound up upgrading to the latest pre-release 1.2.0 edition of `appcompat` to get rid of the problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems somthing like that.
upgrading `appcompat ` and `com.google.android.material:material` to `1.3.0-alpha01` fix the issue

Comment: I also got rid of this error message by upgrading ```appcompat``` to the latest version which is ```1.3.0-rc01```. But, I didn't have to upgrade the ```material``` library.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I experienced this exact same problem today, and was able to solve.
Turns out the issue was a version mismatch between the expected version of `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel` used by the module where the "failing" class is and a *later* version in some other dependent code.

So in my case, my module was using version *2.1.0* of this module, but one of the dependencies was using version *2.2.0*. The code will compile no problem, because gradle resolves the dependency to the latest version; however Android Studio is somehow confused by this situation (not always, because this doesn't happen all the time, but *sometimes* – this isn't the first time I've seen this.)

Therefore solution is: figure out what the latest version of this library is in your app and update your `build.gradle` for this module to point to the same version that gradle is resolving to. Or:

1. run `gradlew app:dependencies`
2. search the result for `lifecycle-viewmodel`
3. update `build.gradle` in your app to depend on `lifecycle-viewmodel` with the version that gradle says it is resolving to
4. Sync project with gradle files

Comment: Also noteworthy, I was able to switch it _back_ to 2.1.0 and the problem didn't come back.

Comment: run ./gradlew app :dependencies in windows !

Answer (score 21):

in my case (an Android module), Android Studio 4.0.1, I get a number of warnings in the IDE related to androidx.lifecycle.HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory,
I have solved the issue by adding this line to build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

thus the beginning of build.gradle becomes:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
...
```

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the problem was solved adding the lifecycle viewmodel dependency in the module of the troubled class.

Answer (score 9):

Add dependency into you build gradle `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:x.x.x` with actual version. For activity you must add `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:x.x.x`. I hope this helps you, in my case it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I added the following lines to build.gradle to solve the same issue in a module:

```
def archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-XXX` dependency **versions must be the same**.

in my case:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

me too have the same problem with this ->

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.0'
```

I changed the version of the **lifecycle-runtime-ktx** dependency from:

> implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.0'

To

> implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'

and now it work.